# Handout: pages layout not correct

Tags: beamer, handout

I'm trying to make a handout version of my presentation, however it seems not succeed. I want 4 slides collaged on 1 page. Can anyone give me hint to fix my problem?

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx,picinpar}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\newcommand{\degre}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}

% ********Trang 1********

\title[\bf KỲ THI THỬ THPT QUỐC GIA NĂM 2016]{\bf PHÂN TÍCH ĐỀ THI THỬ \\  THPT QUỐC GIA NĂM 2016} 
\author[Trần Đình Chiến]{ 
Trường THPT Chuyên\\ 
(Đại học Vinh)} 
\frame{\titlepage} 

% ********Trang 2********

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 1 (1,0 điểm)}\pause 
Khảo sát sự biến thiên và vẽ đồ thị của hàm số $y= x^3-6x^2+9x-1$. 
\end{block} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item \onslide<3->Tập xác định:  \pause
\item \onslide<3->Sự biến thiên: 
\end{itemize} 
\end{frame} 

% ********Trang 3******** 

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize} 
\item Đồ thị: \pause
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
ABCXYZ
\end{center} 
\end{frame} 

% ********Trang 4*******

\begin{frame} 
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 2 (1,0 điểm)} 
Viết phương trình tiếp tuyến của đồ thị hàm số $y=\dfrac{2x+1}{x-1}$, biết rằng tiếp tuyến song song với đường thẳng $d:3x+4y-2=0$. 
\end{block} \pause
\end{frame} 

% ********Trang 5*******

\begin{frame} 
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 3 (1,0 điểm)} 
\begin{itemize}
\item[a)] Cho số phức $z$ thỏa mãn $(1-i)z-1+5i=0$. Tìm phần thực và phần ảo của $z$. 
\item[b)] Cho $\log_{3}{5}=a$. Tính $\log_{\sqrt{45}}{75}$ theo $a$. 
\end{itemize}
\end{block} \pause 
\end{frame} 

% ********Trang 6*******

\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 4 (1,0 điểm)} 
Tính tích phân $I=\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{1}\frac{x+\ln(2x+1)}{(x+1)^2}dx$.
\end{block} \pause
\end{frame} 

% ********Trang 7*******

\begin{frame} 
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 5 (1,0 điểm)} 
Trong không gian với hệ tọa độ $Oxyz$, cho mặt phẳng $(P):x+y+z-7=0$ và đường thẳng $d:\dfrac{x-3}{-2}=\dfrac{y+8}{4}=\dfrac{z}{-1}$. Tìm tọa độ giao điểm của $d$ với $(P)$ và lập phương trình mặt phẳng $(Q)$ chứa $d$ đồng thời vuông góc với $(P)$. 
\end{block} \pause 
\end{frame}

% ********Trang 8*******

\begin{frame} 
\begin{block}{\bf Câu 6 (1,0 điểm)}
\begin{itemize}
\item[a)] Giải phương trình $\cos x+\sin2x=\sin x+\sin2x\cot x$. <br/>
\item[b)] Nhân dịp kỉ niệm ngày Nhà giáo Việt Nam, trường THPT $X$ tuyển chọn được 24 tiết mục văn nghệ tiêu biểu, trong đó lớp $11A$ có 2 tiết mục để công diễn trong toàn trường. Ban tổ chức cho bốc thăm ngẫu nhiên để chia thành 2 buổi công diễn, mỗi buổi 12 tiết mục. Tính xác suất để 2 tiết mục của lớp $11A$ được biểu diễn trong cùng một buổi. 
\end{itemize} 
\end{block} \pause
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is good that you have posted some code but this isn't a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). The idea is to post the smallest possible amount of code that compiles and exhibits your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you and hence much more likely that they will! Also, to turn on code highlighting, use the `{}` symbol in the gui when you insert your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you just need to add the `landscape` option to `\pgfpagesuselayout`. Even better is to surround this command with `\mode<handout>{ ... }` so that you only get four slides to a page in handout mode.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\mode<handout>{
    \pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 1}\lipsum[1]\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 2}\lipsum[1]\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 3}\lipsum[1]\end{frame}
  \begin{frame}{Frame 4}\lipsum[1]\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

Because of the `\mode<handout>{...}` command, if you remove the handout from the document class line, so that it becomes `\documentclass{beamer}`, then you get "normal" slides.